# ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT not working in ROSPY on Hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to use ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT as shown in Console Output Formatting on rosconsole wiki.

I configured my .bashrc as shown below:

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash 
source ~/myproject/devel/setup.bash
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
export ROS_MASTER_URI=<removed_link>
export ROBOT=sim
export ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT='[${severity}] [${node}@${function}:${line}]: ${message}'
```

For C++ I get expected outputs. However for any python program, for example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# license removed for brevity
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():
    # pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    r = rospy.Rate(1)  # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        # str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
        rospy.loginfo("Hello World!")
        # pub.publish(str)
        r.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

I get unformatted outputs like:

```
mjyc@ubuntu:~$ python test.py
[INFO] [WallTime: 1405812621.854884] Hello World!
[INFO] [WallTime: 1405812622.856649] Hello World!
[INFO] [WallTime: 1405812623.856340] Hello World!
[INFO] [WallTime: 1405812624.856789] Hello World!
[INFO] [WallTime: 1405812625.855262] Hello World!
```

Anybody has any clue?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and using hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187166/rosconsole_format-not-working-in-rospy-on-hydro/) by [Andrzej Pronobis](https://answers.ros.org/users/13016/andrzej-pronobis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-07-20

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-07**:
FYI: [ros_comm/pull/519](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/519) adds support for `ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT` to `rospy`. It's currently only merged into `indigo-devel` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Andrzej,

so `rosconsole` is purley a C++ logging related package. rospy's logging seems to be somewhat unrelated. In particular the [logging with rospy](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Logging) tutorial makes no mention of such a configuration of the output.

The only mention of `ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT` in https://github.com/ros/ros_comm is in C++ code and the [code that seems to implent the output formatting in rospy](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/f494ffbad617f1e34e56acbff9023943a542c2f5/tools/rosgraph/src/rosgraph/roslogging.py#L154-L163) is also pretty clearly not configurable in such a way.

It's probably pretty straight forward to implement support for that environment variable also for rospy. The existence of [this file](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/rosgraph/conf/python_logging.conf) suggests to me that you can configure rospy to use your custom stream handler without touching rospy code itself, but I'm sure PR's to improve rospy are welcome.

Cheers,
Niko

**Edit:** Check out the python logging module extesive configuration capabilities here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrzej Pronobis](https://answers.ros.org/users/13016/andrzej-pronobis/) on 2014-07-22**:
Thanks a lot Niko for a very informative answer!

**Comment by [m_jaeyoon_c](https://answers.ros.org/users/13886/m_jaeyoon_c/) on 2014-07-23**:
Thank you!